# Loop the Array Data in each table row

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview

I would like to print out array data in row by row. Data title, data pack name, Time text and data texts are included in array.

My problem is that all these texts are print out row by row. My current situation is that for eg. Data Title 1 is appear in first row. Data Pack Name appears in second row and data text appear in third row.

Actually I would like to show four texts together in row by row:

[image]

```
class Pack: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{

    @IBOutlet weak var packSegmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!
    @IBOutlet weak var packTableView: UITableView!


    let rest = Rest()
    var messages: String! = ""
    var TableData:Array< String > = Array < String >()
    var TableSpeed:Array< String > = Array < String >()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        callRest()
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        var returnValue = 0
        switch (packSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex) {
        case 0:
            returnValue = TableData.count;
            break
        case 1:
            returnValue = TableSpeed.count;
            break
        default:
            break
        }

        return returnValue
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let packCellToReturn = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("packCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PackTableViewCell

        switch (packSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex)
        {
        case 0:
                packCellToReturn.lblPackageName.text = TableData[indexPath.row]
                packCellToReturn.lblPrice.text = TableData[indexPath.row]
                packCellToReturn.lblSpeed.text = TableData[indexPath.row]
                packCellToReturn.lblupdatetime.text = TableData[indexPath.row]
            break
        case 1:
                packCellToReturn.lblPackageName.text = TableSpeed[indexPath.row]
                packCellToReturn.lblPrice.text = TableSpeed[indexPath.row]
                packCellToReturn.lblSpeed.text = TableSpeed[indexPath.row]
                packCellToReturn.lblupdatetime.text = TableSpeed[indexPath.row]
            break
        default:
            break
        }

        return packCellToReturn


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What about your row heights? You can insert these lines in **viewDidLoad**:

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 88.0 //row height I estimated
```

P.S. : Take a look also to your packCell constraints , everything will be setted correctly.

Comment: I think it does not associate with height of the row. It is just about the looping of array and display them in each row by row.

Comment: If you have a label who write over your next row, there is a constraint problem concern cell height or label constraints